# How do I retrieve a file if I undid a folder checkout in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

For reasons unknown, a folder was checked out to me in ClearCase. A coworker was working on a word document stored in that folder. I undid the checkout on the top level folder. Her document disappeared and she doesn't have a local copy. Have I totally screwed her over here? Is there any way we can get it back? Is it stored somewhere on the server and we just can't see it with the standard GUI interface? I was under the impression that you couldn't add to a folder if someone had it checked out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dynamic view, the only place it can still be is in the view storage.

But, dynamic or snapshot, first check the `\yourVob\lost+found` folder: it is for any files:

- added to source control
- with no parent folder referencing it (which is exactly what you have done by undo-checkouting said parent folder of the work document).

See "[About the lost+found directory](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120317)" for more on that special folder.

If you find it there (with an "extended name"), then see "[To move an element from the lost+found directory](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_move_lost_found.htm)" in order to restore the file.