# How to remove a checkout without any view reference in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I have a file in lost+found which is checkedout but I do not see any viewreference. How can i remove the file?

I'm Checking in windows system. When I do a version tree, I see a view that was created in some unix system. I'm not able to get the uuid of the same.

How can I delete such file?

Answer (score 0):

For the checked out state, You should be able to get the view uuid in the same way as in the previous question "[How do I delete check-outs from a particular view in clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29169058/6309)".

That `lost+found` folder is part of a vob and a cleartool describe -b vob:\Avob should list the uuid of the unix view.

But if you are not sure which uuid matches the actual name of the old view you see in the version tree, you can check for that name directly in the registry server.

There are different option:

```
 cleartool rgy_check -views
```

But also, since I have access to the registry server, I can do a simple grep of the name in the var/rgy folder where view_tag is:

```
<user>@<server> /path/to/ClearCase/var/rgy
$ grep -i <view_name> view_*
view_object:-entry=view_object;-hostname=server;-local_path=path/to/<view_name>.vws;-owner=<name>;-view_uuid=e670fe8a.fb0540e5.83f4.7f:82:a6:s8:e1:1a;-attributes=sumview;
view_tag:-entry=view_tag;-tag=<view_name>;-title=<title_View>;-hostname=server;-global_path=\\server\views\path\to\<view_name>.vws;-region=<region>;-view_uuid=e670fe8a.fb0540e5.83f4.7f:82:a6:s8:e1:1a;
```

That way, from then name, you get back the uuid and can remove the checked out state from the vob.

---

Regarding the file itself (in `lost+found`), see technote "[About the lost+found directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120317)", that I mentioned in "[How do I retrieve a file if I undid a folder checkout in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20908903/6309)".

> There are two possible ways to remove an object from the root of the `lost+found`:
>
> - The object can be moved to a new location in the VOB using the [`cleartool mv`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mv.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-46&lang=en) command
> - The object can be permanently deleted from the VOB.

Be careful with the second option ([which involves `rmelem`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941527/6309)), especially in UCM (where that object could have in previous versions baseline labels attached to them)