# Removing files from lost+found directory in clearcase UCM

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I want to delete all the files from lost+found directory in one go from command prompt.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the technote [About the lost+found directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120317#removing-objects)

> ### Removing Objects from `lost+found`
>
> Before taking any steps to clean out the VOB's `lost+found`, please make a backup of the VOB as a safeguard.
>
> There are two possible ways to remove an object from the root of the `lost+found`:
>
> - The object can be moved to a new location in the VOB using the cleartool mv command
> - The object can be permanently deleted from the VOB.

In your case, you would do some `cleartool rmelem -force lost+found/afile`.

```
% pwd
/vobs/myvob/lost+found

% cleartool ls
test.c.f9e4e356252a11d0a41508000993b102@@/main/1    Rule: /main/LATEST

% cleartool rmelem test.c.f9e4e356252a11d0a41508000993b102
```

As I mentioned in "[How to remove a checkout without any view reference in clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29180962/6309)", you need to rmelem the files first, then the folder.

So write a script which does a `cleartool find -type f myVob/loast+found` first, then a `find -type d`.

You can combine a cleartool find with an `-exec` directive calling [`cleartool rmelem`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmelem.htm):

```
 ... -exec "cleartool rmelem -force \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Be *very* careful with that rmelem command: once an element is remove from the vob, it cannot be recovered.