# I have a file on three branches. How do I make sure it only exists on one branch?

Tags: branch, clearcase

## Background

I have a clearcase file that has changes on 3 different branches.  I am refactoring this file so that, within the same directory, it only exists on one branch.  The files on the other branches I will move to their own special directories.

## Question

How do I remove the versions of a file on different branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [`cleartool rmname`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmname.htm), done in a view set to the relevant branch, should be enough.
See a detailed description of that command in "[About `cleartool rmname` and checkouts](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/about-cleartool-rmname-and-checkouts)"

This is far safer than a [`cleartool rmelem`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmelem.htm), which would completely deletes one or more elements.

Comment: `cleartool rmelem` is essentially forbidden to use at my company, even for one file unless you have a signoff from every lead architect to do so.

Comment: @isakbob That seems sensible. I only used it to clean-up my VOB `lost+found` folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342351/6309